# Pulling data in a for loop where data sometimes does not exist

Tags: json, excel, vba, api, for-loop

Let's say I have four data values and one of them exists sometimes.
My For loop crashes because the path doesn't exist.
I would like to pass a "" in the cell instead of crashing.

`myJSON.data[i].bank[0].money` <- this part is my problem, because the `bank[0].money` sometimes doesn't exist.
I would like to keep the cell empty.
I tried an If but I didn't get it formatted properly, same goes for error handling.

```vb
Sub DATA()
    Set RDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dlist = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    JSON_String = Form.fromURL("exampleurl")
    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        With .parentWindow
            .execScript "var myJSON = " & JSON_String & ", csvstring = '';for (i = 0; i < myJSON.data.length; i++) {csvstring += myJSON.data[i].name + ',' + myJSON.data[i].bank[0].money + ',' + myJSON.data[i].location + ',' + myJSON.data[i].planneddate + ';';};"
            RData = Split(.csvstring, ";")
        End With
    End With
    For i = 0 To UBound(RData) - 1
        DaData = Split(RData(i), ",")
        If DaData(0) <> "null" Then RDict(DaData(0)) = DaData
    Next i
    Dim RSheet() As Variant
    If RDict.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim RSheet(2 To RDict.Count + 2, 1 To 7)
        i = 0
        For Each D In RDict
            datalist(RDict(Da)(2)) = True
            For j = 0 To 6
                RSheet(i + 2, j + 1) = RDict(Da)(j)
            Next j
            i = i + 1
        Next Da
        RSData.Cells(2, 1).Resize(i, 6) = RSheet
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: is this the problem? `If DaData(0) <> "null" `

Comment: No it seems like this "myJSON.data[i].bank[0].money" is the problem, because the path does not exsist allways

Comment: Where is your `if operation` that failed?

Comment: I removed it, because i didnt get it build properly

Comment: Good rule of thumb on SO - It's always helpful if you show your code you tried

Comment: Oh i didnt know that, i will do it in the further thank you!

Comment: It would be easier I think to use the VBA-JSON library to parse the JSON.  https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON   Even if you're comfortable in jscript, this hybrid approach feels a bit clunky.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle null by using [optional chaining](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-optional-chaining/) with default nullish coalescing (#3 in example).

**Something like this should work**

Change `myJSON.data[i]?.bank[0]?.money`

To `myJSON.data[i]?.bank[0]?.money ?? 'Unknown'`

You can do the same with your other variables (`myJSON.data[i].location` and `myJSON.data[i].planneddate`) if they have the potential to be undefined or null as well

**EDIT - Use Optional IF when optional chaining is not available**

If that feature is not available in HTMLDocument's javascript maybe you can use basic conditional if?

This should work for undefined object, because `undefined is == null`

```
(myJSON.data[i].bank[0].money != null ? myJSON.data[i].bank[0].money : '-')
```

Comment: I changed it but now i get this error "-2147352319 (80020101)"

Comment: Do you have a javascript console you can do some troubleshooting in? `exampleurl` doesn't give us anything to work with

Comment: Perhaps that feature is not available in Microsoft HTMLDocument javascript? Try the basic conditional if in my edited answer

Comment: ECMAScript version support in `htmlfile` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65207848/using-htmlfile-com-object-to-access-the-getownpropertydescriptor-method-of-an

Comment: https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_logical_nullish_assignment

Comment: Okay the If condition worked, thank you very much this wars bothering me for a couple of days :)

Comment: Can you mark it as the answer then (with the checkmark) or at least upvote as helpful?